# Access function from a library

Tags: javascript

I'm using [color.js](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/colors.js), and I want to convert a string to an RGB color. I know it's possible to do that because there's a [function at line 344](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/colors.js#L344) that does it. I guess the only problem is accessing it. (Obviously from another file.)

I tried 2 different ways, but they both gave me an error:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5manvdn2/)

```js
var myColor = new Colors();
console.log(myColor.convertColor('rgb(100, 50, 100)', 'txt2RGB'));
console.log(myColor.ColorConverter.txt2color('rgb(100, 50, 100)'));
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/PitPik/colorPicker/master/colors.js"></script>
```

Comment: Make sure your script is **after** the `<script>` tag that loads the library.

Comment: I think that function is exposed as `convert`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line gets an error because there's no text-to-RGB conversion in the library. The only thing that text can be converted to is color, so

```
console.log(myColor.convertColor('rgb(100, 50, 100)', 'txt2color'));
```

will work.

The problem with your second line is that `ColorConverter` is a local variable within the `Colors()` function, it's not a property of the object. It's only intended to be called internally within the library. Since there's no `myColor.ColorConverter` property, the value of this is `undefined`, so trying to access `myColor.ColorConverter.txt2color` reports the error of trying to read a property of `undefined`.

Comment: getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'txt2color' of undefined` error

Comment: That's because there's no `myColor.ColorConverter` property, as I explained in my answer. I've added more details to it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! That works! So the way I access the rgb value is by adding `.rgb` at the end. The problem I'm having is that it gives decimal values, `[0, 1]` How can I get it with whole values, [0, 255]`? I can convert it from rgb2RGB, but is there an easier way, or a right way of doing it?

Comment: Probably, but I'm not going to try to figure it out from the code.